# Mount encrypted Synology folder on non-Synology platform

Tags: encryption, mount, nas, synology, ecryptfs

I sold my Synology NAS box on eBay while keeping the HDDs.  I completely forgot that I had encrypted some of my "Shared Folders".  Now I desperately need to mount these `@Test@` folders using anything but Synology's DSM.  On Synology I could use the terminal to mount them (`synoshare --enc_mount Test 12345678`).  Is there any way to mount these folders on *non*-Synology *nix?  I.e., is there something identical to `synoshare` on other *nix OS?

Comment: try this  [post](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=49888.0) from 2013 if it still applies.

Comment: @meuh  Awesome find, thank you very much.  I googled for this for an entire afternoon.  Given that they updated the post / PDF 4 months ago, I think that this will be the answer.  Please make your comment an answer and I will happy accept it.